# Can I claim American Opportunity Credit if I have a pause in my education?

Tags: united-states, income-tax

I claimed the "American Opportunity Credit" for 2012 and 2013, I then quit school and now I have a few courses to do to get my degree. Can I still use American Opportunity Credit two more times? Do I have to be a full time student in order to claim it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have claimed it in the past twice, you can claim it up to two more times. You can only claim the credit four times in your lifetime, but there is no requirement that the years be consecutive.

You do not need to be a full time student, but you need to be enrolled at least half time during one academic period that begins during the tax year you are claiming the credit for, and you must be an undergraduate, not yet having earned a four-year degree.

From the IRS [American Opportunity Tax Credit](https://www.irs.gov/credits-deductions/individuals/aotc):

> To be eligible for AOTC, the student must:
>
> - Be pursuing a degree or other recognized education credential
> - Be enrolled at least half time for at least one academic period* beginning in the tax year
> - Not have finished the first four years of higher education at the beginning of the tax year
> - Not have claimed the AOTC or the former Hope credit for more than four tax years
> - Not have a felony drug conviction at the end of the tax year

Comment: You can’t say if they can claim it since you don’t know if they meet those requirements. Also that’s exactly the same information from the IRS that I had already posted.

Comment: @T.M. Yes, I posted the same quote you did, but you didn’t explicitly answer either of his questions: “Can I use it two more times?” and “Do I have to be a full time student?”

Comment: I don’t really care about the credit for the answer, but we can’t actually answer the first question beyond it is available two more times if he qualifies and the second question is clearly answered in what I and you posted.

Answer (score -1):

[The IRS says](https://www.irs.gov/credits-deductions/individuals/aotc):

> To be eligible for AOTC, the student must:
>
> - Be pursuing a degree or other recognized education credential
> - Be enrolled at least half time for at least one academic period* beginning in the tax year
> - Not have finished the first four years of higher education at the
>     beginning of the tax year
> - Not have claimed the AOTC or the former
>     Hope credit for more than four tax years
> - Not have a felony drug
>     conviction at the end of the tax year

It’s actually not clear on what they mean by finished the first four years whether that’s four years of attending school or getting a degree.